# React routing for login using symfony

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony

I have an issue, I have a symfony project using react, for the routes to be able to reach react or the back end I have a default controller defined like this:

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{reactRouting}", name="home",  requirements={"reactRouting"="^(?!api).+"},defaults={"reactRouting": null})
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
```

this way, all the routes besides the ones coming from api/ 'stay' in react, meaning to reach the back end I need a route that starts with /api.
Now this is my security.yaml:

```
security:
    #enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Students:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Students
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: false
            lazy: true
            pattern: ^/api/
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
            logout:
                  path: app_logout
                  target: /
                  invalidate_session: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS}
         - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS}
         - { path: ^/api/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS}
         - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_STUDENT}
```

So for login, I want to get to my LoginController.php but if I do /login, it won't go anywhere and if I do /api/login it does to my tokenAuthenticator which I don't want either.

What can I do that /api/login or /login (the url doesn't really matters to me) gets to my LoginController?

```
 /**
     * @Route("/api/login", name="app_login")
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function login(Request $request): Response
    { //some code}
```

I tried adding the form_login in the security.yaml but without success, I tried json_login also...
Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: "I do /login, it won't go anywhere" - what does that mean?

Comment: meaning if I use the route /login, it doesn't hit the back end because it's stopped by requirements={"reactRouting"="^(?!api).+"} in the defaultController

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where's the code to handle that route?